# Saving Emojis in CKEditor (Emojione) in DB

Tags: ckeditor, emojione

I have "Empjione" (https://github.com/braune-digital/ckeditor-emojione)  as an add-on in a CKEditor 4 installation.  However, most of the emojis don't get saved to the DB (some do though). I'm saving the output of the CKEditor as HTML into the DB.

Here are a few that do get saved: ❤️, ☝️, ⚠️

Here are a few that don't get saved: , ,

For example, this: `some text  now more text`
Ends up as this in my DB: `<p>some text&nbsp;`

Any thoughts?  Or is there a better emoji add-on that anyone knows of?

Comment: What kind of database and backend are you using?

Comment: @TidyDev: MySQL / PHP MyAdmin

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with CKEditor but rather MySQL. Your data is likely using `utf8`. MySQL’s `utf8` actually only allows three bytes per character; the emojis that use 4 bytes aren’t saving. If you were running MySQL in strict mode it would give you an `Incorrect string value` error.

You can fix this by changing your database's character set to `utf8mb4`.

[This DBA Stack Exchange post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21684/94504) explains how to do this.